# Re-declare a variable in bash to call a function with a different outcome

Tags: bash

I have a script in bash which is executed every minute via cron as below. The script declares initialising as true and then calls the initialiseBoot function which contains while loop which should continually echo 'Initialising' until initialising=false, which is when it should then echo "Not initialising". This should continue until the ping is successful. When the cron job is run again after a successful ping, I would like it to go straight to "Not initialising" but wasn't sure how I could achieve that either. Here's what I have so far:-

```
initialising=true

function initialiseBoot {
 while true; do
    if [ "$initialising" = true ]; then
        echo "Initialising"
    else
        echo "Not initialising"
    fi
 done
}
# Call initialiseBoot function
initialiseBoot

# If host can ping 8.8.8.8
if [ ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 ]; then
    echo "Ping success"

     while true; do
        echo "Ping failed"
     done
else
    initialising=false
fi
```

The problem is that even if the ping fails, it seems initialise never gets set to false, therefore I never see "Not initialising", or at least that is my understanding of it. In any case, I never see "Not initialsing" even if I echo the ping so I know it is succeeding.

Comment: `[` is a command.  `if [ ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 ]; then` should be `if  ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 ; then`.  In other words, loose the `[` (or `test`) command.

Comment: I have changed it to as you suggested, if ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 ; then
    echo "Ping success". However, it seems it still never gets into setting intiialising=false (when the ping fails) and therefore falling into "Not initialising"

Comment: Variables don't persist between different runs of the script. Every time the script runs, it starts fresh.

Comment: And even if they did persist, the first thing this script does is set it back to `true`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. However, the script is continually outputting "Not initialising" even if I execute it manually.

Comment: I just tried it, and it continually prints "Initializing"

Comment: `while true; ` is an infinite loop. How is it ever supposed to get out of the loop?

Comment: Anyway, if you need to keep state between script executions, put it in a file.

Comment: Yeah, that is a problem. Basically, I wanted it to print "Initialising" if does not successfully ping and "Not initialising" if the ping succeeds. But repeat, essentially re-try to ping in the hope that eventually the ping will succeed and I'll see "Not initialising"

Answer (score 0):

You can't use shell variables to keep state between executions of a script, they don't persist across executions. Instead, store the state in a file.

```
initializing=true
if [ -r /tmp/myscript.initializing ];
    initializing=$(</tmp/myscript.initializing)
fi

if [ "$initializing" = true ]
then echo "Initializing"
else echo "Not Initializing"
fi

...

echo "false" > /tmp/myscript.initializing
```

Comment: That looks like a race condition to me, since `...` might take longer than the interval between runs. (Perhaps "initializing" was not a good name; maybe OP meant "uninitialized". The intended logic isn't clear to me.) Best way to avoid the race condition is to use the *existence* of the file as a flag, not its contents, since it is possible to atomically create-or-fail (on local filesystems, anyway).